# how to draw line beetween two places in mapview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView12 viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *overlayView = nil;

    if (nil == overlayView) 
    {       
        overlayView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] autorelease];

        overlayView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        overlayView.lineWidth   = 5.0;  
    }

    return overlayView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made app on mapview. so just if you want get proper path you have to use KMLViewer or use GoogleMaps .In google Maps u can do this code

NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=

%f,%f",sourcelocation.latitude,sourcelocation.longitude,destinationlocation.latitude,destin

ationlocation.longitude];

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]];
```

Answer (score 1):

i think, you want to draw the proper line between to station then use the KMLparser for that.

use the subclass of it and then implemnet this method :

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    return [kml viewForOverlay:overlay];
}


 //  add the pin in mapview

    -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
        return [kml viewForAnnotation:annotation];
    }
```